# Expected length of longest stick in a stick snapping process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Starting with a single stick of unit length, a point $p \in (0, 1)$ is picked uniformly at random along the stick and the stick is snapped, producing two sticks of length $p$ and $1-p$.

At each next stage, a stick is picked uniformly at random, and a point is picked uniformly at random along the length of that stick, and it is snapped.

**Question:** After n snaps, what is the expected length of the longest remaining stick?

**Remarks:**

Myself and a friend of mine did some simulations and found some pretty unexpected results. The expected value after $500$ splits is approximately $0.2098$, which is massive for that many splits, at least intuitively.

On the other hand, it can be proven rather easily that the expected value does go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. But the decay seems extremely slow.

Comment: Sort of similar process: https://mathoverflow.net/q/415252

Comment: In case you haven't seen the stick-breaking constructions of the beta and Dirichlet processes, you may find the analysis interesting.

Comment: @BillBradley I will check it out, thanks!

Comment: There is a natural interpolation between this question and the one Sam Hopkins links: Let $0 \leq p \leq \infty$. If the stick has been broken into $n$ pieces, of lengths $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$, then pick up the $j$-th piece with probability $x_j^p/\sum_i x_i^p$, and break that piece at a uniformly random position. This question is $p=0$, and the other is $p = \infty$. Unfortunately, only $p=1$ seems easy to analyze.

Comment: Actually, $p=1$ doesn't seem easy either ...

Comment: Just my naive guess: if $X_n$ is the length of the longest stick after $n-1$ snaps, isn't then $E(X_{n+1} \mid X_n) = \frac{n-1}{n} X_n + \frac{1}{2n} X_n$? I admit I'm not sure about the notation anymore... The reasoning is that you have a chance of $\frac{1}{n}$ of snapping the longest stick, in which case $X_{n+1}$ has expected length $1/2E(X_n)$; if you break another stick - with probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$ - the expected length is unchanged, namely $E(X_n)$. From this you would get the recursive formula $E(X_{n+1}) = (1-\frac{1}{2n})E(X_n)$.

Comment: I like @LeoMoos idea, but two corrections. First, there is some probability that, after you snap the longest stick, the new longest stick won't be one of the two halves of the old longest stick. So this is a lower bound, not an equality. Also, I think it should be $(3/4) E(X_n)$, not $(1/2) E(X_n)$, since you split the stick in half and take the larger of the two halves.

Comment: Combining those, I think we have $E(X_{n+1}) \geq (1-\tfrac{1}{4n}) E(X_n)$ and hence $E(X_{n+1}) \geq (1-\tfrac{1}{4n})(1-\tfrac{1}{4n-4})(1-\tfrac{1}{4n-8}) \cdots \approx \tfrac{1}{n^{1/4}}$.

Comment: This seems too good to be true, but $1/\sqrt[4]{500}$ is $0.211$, matching the OP's data.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer You're right, I was a bit sloppy... Thanks for the corrections. Considering your comments, it seems a bit finicky getting an exact (and useful) recursion formula, but perhaps the lower bound has some value.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: the case $p=1$ corresponds to breaking at $n$ independent uniformly random points, no? That does seem much simpler.

Comment: @SamHopkins Right, that's why I thought it would be tractable. But then I tried to work out what I thought the maximum gap between n id uniform variables would be, and it still seems hard.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer It seems like the problem of the maximum gap between $n$ uniform variables is handled [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999612/average-minimum-distance-between-n-points-generate-i-i-d-with-uniform-dist?fbclid=IwAR0aRrS5al-3h2Iw5aSgCmrHElnfd-YtUVFal4tQpy655Cizkvs7P1D_eC4).

Comment: @NateRiver Nice, though that's the minimum, not the maximum. It probably is adaptable.

Comment: Oh whoops, you’re right..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that the length of the longest stick is of order $n^{2\sqrt{2}-3} = n^{-0.171\ldots}$ as $n\to\infty$. This follows from a discrete-time analogue of the homogeneous fragmentation process, see chapter 1.5 of J. Bertoin, *Random fragmentation and coagulation processes*. Vol. 102. Cambridge University Press, 2006.

Let us denote by $X_{n,0} \geq X_{n,1} \geq \cdots \geq X_{n,n}$ the ordered sizes of the sticks after $n$ snaps. The first result we need is the following.

**Lemma:** $\chi_{n}(p) := \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=0}^n X_{n,i}^p\right] = \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{2}{1+p}\right)_n,$ where $(a)_n=a(a+1)\cdots (a+n-1)$  is the rising Pochhammer symbol.

**Proof:** We have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=0}^n X_{n,i}^p\middle| X_{n-1,0},\ldots\right] &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\Big(\mathbb{E}\left[x^p + (X_{n-1,k}-x)^p\middle|X_{n-1,k}\right]+\sum_{\substack{i=0\\i\neq k}}^{n-1}X_{n-1,i}^p\Big)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{2}{p+1}+n-1\right)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}X_{n-1,i}^p,
\end{align*}
where $x$ is uniform in $(0,X_{n-1,k})$. Hence $\chi_n(p) = \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{2}{p+1}+n-1\right) \chi_{n-1}(p)$.
Together with $\chi_0(p)=1$, this gives the claimed formula for $\chi_n(p)$. $\square$

Following Corollary 1.4 in Bertoin's book, we note that
\begin{equation}
n^{\frac{p-1}{p+1}} \chi_n(p) = \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{p+1}\right)} + O(n^{-1}).
\end{equation}
In particular it is bounded for any $p>-1$. Since $X_{n,0}^p < \sum_{i=0}^n X_{n,i}^p$, we deduce that $n^{\frac{p-1}{p+1}}X_{n,0}^p$ is bounded as $n\to\infty$. Hence
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log X_{n,0}}{\log n} \leq -\frac{1}{p}\frac{p-1}{p+1} \leq -\frac{1}{\bar{p}}\frac{\bar{p}-1}{\bar{p}+1} = 2\sqrt{2}-3,
\end{equation}
because the maximum $\bar{p}$ of $-\frac{1}{p}\frac{p-1}{p+1}$ is achieved at $\bar{p} = 1+\sqrt{2}$.
Similarly one can derive a matching lower bound by noting that
\begin{equation}
X_{n,0}^\epsilon \geq \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}X_{n,i}^p}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}X_{n,i}^{p-\epsilon}}
\end{equation}
for any $\epsilon>0$, which implies
\begin{equation}
\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log X_{n,0}}{\log n} \geq - \frac{\frac{p-1}{p+1} - \frac{p-\epsilon-1}{p-\epsilon+1}}{\epsilon} 
\end{equation}
for any $\epsilon>0$ and $0<p<\bar{p}$. Letting $\epsilon$ approach $0$ and $p$ approach $\bar{p}$, we thus have
\begin{equation}
\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log X_{n,0}}{\log n} \geq -\frac{2}{(1-\bar{p})^2}=2\sqrt{2}-3.
\end{equation}
We may therefore conclude that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log X_{n,0}}{\log n} =2\sqrt{2}-3.
\end{equation}

Comment: I think this is as close to a complete answer as one can hope for - asymptotics in $n$. So I have accepted the answer, though others are still very welcome to contribute. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: I am confused about the lower bound. You have $X_{n,0}^{\epsilon} \geq \frac{\sum_k X_{n,k}^p}{\sum_k X_{n,k}^{p-\epsilon}}$. How do you go from there to the lower bound on $\frac{\log X_{n,0}}{\log n}$. At first I thought you were saying that $\mathbb{B}(X_{n,0}^{\epsilon}) \geq \frac{\mathbb{E}(\sum_k X_{n,k}^p)}{\mathbb{E}(\sum_k X_{n,k}^{p-\epsilon})}$, but I don't see how to take the division outside the expectation. Also, you say the next line is  only good for $0 < p < \overline{p}$, which suggests you are doing something else; could you please spell out what it is?

Comment: Some of this is probably my discomfort with probabilistic language. When you say $\lim \text{sup} \frac{\log X_n}{\log n}$ is less than something, or $\lim \text{inf} \frac{\log X_n}{\log n}$ is more than something, you mean with probability $1$, right? As compared to $X_{n,0}^{\epsilon} \geq \frac{\sum_k X_{n,k}^p}{\sum_k X_{n,k}^{p-\epsilon}}$, which is literally true everywhere in the probability space?

Comment: Yes, I have been skipping corners especially on the lower bound. When I find some time I will add some details. Essentially I am just translating the proof of Corollary 1.4 in the book to the discrete setting, so in the meantime if you wish (and can access the book) you could have a look there for the proper arguments.

Comment: Thanks! At this point, I think I have found a way to fix the argument that I am satisfied with, so don't feel a need to rush on my account. Maybe I'll add it as a comment if I get some time.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE#2**. Just to illustrate how the complexity of exact expressions grows, these are the first three:
\begin{split}
n=1:~~~& \frac{3}{4} = 0.75\\
n=2:~~~& \frac38 + \log\frac43 = 0.662682072451781\ldots\\
n=3:~~~& \frac{5+4\pi^{2}}{24}-\log(2)^{2}+\frac{89 \log(2)}{18}-\frac{17 \log(3)}{6}+\frac{2 \log(3) \log(2)}{3}-\frac{2 \Re\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}(\tfrac{3}{2})}{3} = 0.612043787903219\ldots
\end{split}

**UPDATE#1**. As pointed out in the comments, the recurrence for $L(n)$ derived below gives only a lower bound.

---

<s>Let $L(n)$ be the expected length of the longest stick after $n$ snaps.</s> Consider the two sticks resulted from the first snap, call them left and right. Noticing that the probability of exactly $k\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ out of the following $n-1$ snaps happening in the (descendants of) left stick equals $\frac1n$, we get a recurrence formula starting at $L(0)=1$:

\begin{split}
L(n) &= \frac1n \int_0^1 {\rm d}p\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \max\{\ pL(k),\ (1-p)L(n-1-k)\ \}\\
&= \frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} L(k) - \frac{L(k)L(n-1-k)}{2(L(k)+L(n-1-k))}.
\end{split}
(simplified per David E Speyer's suggestion)

Here is a [sample Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw1zkEKwyAQBdC94B3-UttqtMtCoAfIHUIxSsV2EozeP0bIbIZ58Pnzdh_39cscKrkSV-Js8QGTIPniDG2yLzUTLGIAjaOB_-0ee_2LSSQJhXPdWkBZleTQ9X6dcngirBkJkSCM1o0bthbOTqfuVmtrrr4tRyqCHv0HeQDqFSnA&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) computing $L(n)$ for $n=1..10$.

Comment: I get that $\int_{p=0}^1 \max(pA, (1-p)B) dp = \tfrac{A^2+AB+B^2}{2A+2B}$, so you can interchange the sum and the integral and remove the integral.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Good point! Thanks!

Comment: What a terrifying looking recurrence, haha.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Actually, I'm not sure why the recurrence should involve a $\text{max}$ over the expected values, seems like its the pointwise (in $\omega$) values that are relevant no? Could you clarify a bit as to how the recurrence is obtained?

Comment: @NateRiver: For each fixed $k$, the maximum length is either coming from the left stick with expected value $pL(k)$ or from the right stick with expected value $(1-p)L(n-1-k)$, with the resulted expected value being maximum of the two. I'm not sure what is $\omega$ you refer to.

Comment: By $\omega$ I mean the random parameter, that is, the element of the probability space $\Omega$. The maximum length comes from either the left sticks descendants or the right sticks, but it seems what we want is something of the form $\mathbb E[\text{max}(\text{left}, \text{ right})]$. It is not clear to me how to move the expectation inside the max.

Comment: I think Nate River is right. Concerning the reasoning in your comment, I cannot attach a meaning to the expectation over a set. In fact, $E\max(X,Y)>\max(EX,EY)$ if $P(X>Y)>0$ and $P(X<Y)>0$. Also, your $L(500)=0.18\ldots$ is a bit less than the simulated value $0.20\ldots$, which seems to be due to the strict inequalities of the form $E\max(X,Y)>\max(EX,EY)$.

Comment: Hm let us be more precise - using $l$, $r$ to denote left and right, we have $\mathbb E[\text{max}(l, r)] = \mathbb E[\mathbf 1_{\Omega_1} l] + \mathbb E[\mathbf 1_{\Omega_2} r] \neq \max(\mathbb E[l], \mathbb E[r])$ in general. Noting that neither of us have used anything special about $l$ or $r$, one can just pick arbitrarily these random variables and see that this doesn’t hold in general.

Comment: @NateRiver: I agree. Perhaps,  the easiest way to see this non-equality is to notice that if, say, $\mathbb{E}[l]>\mathbb{E}[r]$, then $\max(\mathbb{E}[l],\mathbb{E}[r])$ does not depend on $r$, while $\mathbb{E}[\max(l,r)]$ may depend on $r$. It means that $L(n)$ provides only a lower bound for the true answer (as noticed by Iosif Pinelis above).

Comment: Numerically, this seems to be slightly tighter, but very close to, the bound $(1-1/4)(1-1/8) \cdots (1-1/(4n))$ that I point out in comments above.

Answer (score 3):

**This is <s>intermediate between an answer, and</s> a long comment on Max Alekseyev's post.**

As discussed in the comments below his answer, there is a flaw in his post, so that it gives a lower bound.  But there's a straightforward way to progress past the flaw.  Unfortunately, there's a further obstruction that I do not see how to proceed beyond.

**Begin with a slight generalization.**  Start with a single node of length $s$, and build a random tree as follows:

- Select a leaf node $n$ uniformly at random.  Call its weight $w$.
- Select $p\in[0,1]$ uniformly at random.
- Attach two children to $n$ of weight $pw$ and $(1-p)w$.

Your problem asks: if $s=1$, what is the largest weight of a leaf, when there are $n$ nodes?  Call this random variable $X^0_n$; in the general case, that length scales to $sX^0_n$.

**As Max Alekseyev noticed, there is a natural recurrence structure to this tree.**  For notational convenience, suppose $n+1$ nodes.  The root node has two children, weighted $P$ and $1-P$; let there be $K$ and $n-K$ nodes beneath each (inclusive); then $K$ is chosen uniformly from $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$.  Take two iid copies of $X^0$, called $X^1$ and $X^2$.  Since leaf nodes must descend from the children of the root, $$(X_{n+1}^0|K,P)=\max(PX^1_K,(1-P)X^2_{n-K})$$

**To proceed exactly, introduce a CDF-like function.**  Let $F_n(t)=\mathbb{P}\left[{X_n\leq\frac{1}{t}}\right]$; then \begin{align*}
(n+1)F_{n+1}(t)&=(n+1)\mathbb{P}\left[{X_n^0\leq\frac{1}{t}}\right] \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n{\int_0^1{\mathbb{P}\left[{\max(PX^1_K,(1-P)X^2_{n-K})\leq\frac{1}{t}}\middle|{K=k,|P-p|\leq dp}\right]}} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n{\int_0^1{\mathbb{P}\left[{pX^1_k\leq\frac{1}{t}}\wedge{(1-p)X^2_{n-k}\leq\frac{1}{t}}\right]\,dp}} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n{\int_0^1{F_k(pt)F_{n-k}((1-p)t)\,dp}}
\end{align*}

**The finite sum is a discrete convolution, and can be eliminated by passing to generating functions.**  Let $\mathcal{F}(t,z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{F_n(t)z^n}$.  Then $$\mathcal{F}(pt,z)\mathcal{F}((1-p)t,z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=0}^n{F_k(pt)F_{n-k}((1-p)t)z^n}}$$  Integrating in $p$ recovers the recurrence from above, which simplifies to \begin{gather*}
\frac{\mathcal{F}(t,z)}{\partial z}=\int_0^1{\mathcal{F}(pt,z)\mathcal{F}((1-p)t,z)\,dp} \\
\mathcal{F}(t,0)=F_0(t)=\begin{cases}t&0<t\leq1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{gather*}  Note that $F_n(t)=0$ for $t<0$, so that we can extend the bounds of integration to $\mathbb{R}$ without effect.

**The other integral can *almost* be eliminated via the Fourier transform.**  Now let $\mathcal{G}(u,z)=\int_\mathbb{R}{\mathcal{F}(t,z)e^{uti}\,dt}$.  Then \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\mathcal{G}(u,z)}{\partial z}&=\int_\mathbb{R}{\frac{\mathcal{F}(t,z)}{\partial z}e^{uti}\,dt} \\
&=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}{e^{upti}\mathcal{F}(pt,z)\cdot e^{u(1-p)ti}\mathcal{F}((1-p)t,z)\,d^2(p,t)} \\
&=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}{e^{\alpha ui}\mathcal{F}(\alpha,z)\cdot e^{\beta ui}\mathcal{F}(\beta,z)\,\frac{d^2(\alpha,\beta)}{\alpha+\beta}}
\end{align*}  If the $\alpha+\beta$ in the denominator could be removed (say, by tweaking the definition of $F_n$ and using an analogous integral transform), then the last line would simplify to $\mathcal{G}(u,z)^2$.

**Unfortunately, I do not know an integral transform that avoids the extra $\alpha+\beta$ term.**  Nevertheless, let me indulge and sketch the the argument after such a gap were filled, although I'm sure the structure of the argument will come as little surprise to most readers.

Suppose the necessary integral transform has $L^2$ adjoint given by kernel $\hat{I}$ and define $$\alpha(u)=\int_1^\infty{\frac{\hat{I}(t)}{t^2}\,dt}$$  (Yes, one probably needs a little care to show that this integral converges.  But it's ultimately just calculating an explicit integral.)

In the OP, you ask for \begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_n]&=\int_0^1{\mathbb{P}[X_n\leq t]\,dt} \\
&=\int_0^1{F_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\,dt} \\
&=\int_1^\infty{F_n(u)\,\frac{du}{u^2}}
\end{align*} which has generating function $$\mathcal{E}(z)=\int_1^\infty{\mathcal{F}(t,z)\,\frac{dt}{t^2}}=\int_\mathbb{R}{\overline{\alpha(u)}\mathcal{G}(u,z)\,du}$$  Thus it suffices to have an explicit formula for $\mathcal{G}$.

From the known value of $\mathcal{F}(t,0)$, $$\mathcal{G}(u,0)=\frac{1-e^{ui}(1-ui)}{u^2}$$  The differential equation above is then an ODE that uniquely determines $\mathcal{G}$ as some locally-$C^{\infty}$ function $$\mathcal{G}(u,z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{g_n(u)z^n}$$  Comparing coefficients of $z^n$, $$\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\int_\mathbb{R}{\overline{\alpha(u)}g_n(u)\,du}$$ and so the problem reduces to estimating an explicit integral.

Comment: Even if the $n^{-1/4}$ bound is wrong, we certainly have a lower bound of $n^{-1}$, since that is the average length of a piece!

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Yes; I should think the error is in my calculation, not yours.  (I've screwed up problems like this before.)  But I know of analogous problems for which the structure of the argument is sound; there should just be some fortuitous cancellations that end up with an integral that is $\approx n^{-1/4}$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: Ah, crap.  That is the error, and I don't see a way to fix it.  Thanks for wading through my equations.

Comment: @JacobManaker: Wouldn't $F_n(t)=\sqrt t\,\mathbb{P}\left[{X_n\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt t}}\right]$ do the job by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a few empirical results that might be helpful, particularly in lending credence towards some of the theories suggested in other posts.  I ran 10,000 simulations, and for each one, broke the stick 10,000 times, tracking the longest portion at each step.  Here's the results:
[image]

and the same data plotted on a log scale:
[image]

You may notice a highlighted $\pm 1 \sigma$ region mentioned on the legend; the corresponding confidence interval is so tight that it's hard to see.

I added two dotted lines corresponding to two rates of decay mentioned in other posts: $d(n) \propto n^{2\sqrt{2}-3}$ and $d(n) \propto (1-\frac{1}{4n-4})d(n-1)$.

The two hypotheses are intended as asymptotic descriptions, so if we plot them directly, they have large and distracting offsets.  I "fixed" that by multiplying by the appropriate constant to make the plots intersect the empirical mean at $x=1000$.  (For instance, the dotted green line is actually $0.591 n^{2\sqrt{2}-3}$.)

Incidentally, we can compute our own version of the expected length after the 500th split. I ran 1 million simulations and observe an empirical mean of $0.2076537 \pm 0.0001231$.  (The $\pm$ part is one standard deviation for the estimate.)

Comment: I don't understand why $n^{2 \sqrt{2} - 3} \approx n^{-0.17}$ is drawn below $\prod_{k=1}^n (1-1/(4k)) \approx n^{-0.25}$. We should have $n^{-0.25} < n^{-0.17}$.

Comment: Good question, @DavidESpeyer ! I'll double-check...

Comment: Ah... this seems to be an artifact of my additive "fix" to shift the plots onto the same scale.  A multiplicative fit paints a different picture (with the expected ordering of the estimates).  I'll run a higher-quality version and repost when it's done...

Comment: OK, I switched from additive to multiplicative fit, and the lower bound has actually become a lower bound.  I wonder if there's a more thoughtful way to go about fitting these curves.